# How to change "." to "-" in Ms word heading?

Tags: microsoft-word

I need to change . to - for all heading.
For example, in  heading 2 : change 2.1.1 to 2-1-1 .

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are those numbers typed for each heading or automatically set through styles / multi level list?

Comment: Hi @Máté Juhász , all of them automatically generated. On the Home tab, in the Paragraph group, I used Multilevel List.

Comment: Have you tried "Define New MultiLevel List" at the bottom of that menu?

Comment: Hi @cybernetic.nomad No,I didn't see it.